# What is the reason that moving iron instrument can measure both AC and DC but moving coil instrument can't?

Tags: ac, dc, components

**What is the reason that moving iron instrument could measure both AC and DC but moving coil instrument can't?**

( moving coil can't respond quickly as the AC changes its direction so stays at zero - is the explanation i have listen till now )

[i tried to get my doubt clear but couldn't find what i was searching for](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/108105053/pdf/L-42(GDR)(ET)%20((EE)NPTEL).pdf)

Comment: Instead of listening to / waiting for answers why not do your own research. Figure out how each model works. Many things become obvious when you understand how things work.

Comment: i did research before posting it here..i have posted one of the place i searched for

Answer (score 1):

A moving coil meter uses a magnet and this naturally means that the needle moves clockwise for a positive current and anti-clockwise for negative current. The average effect (due to mechanism inertia) and an applied AC frequency of 50 or 60 Hz usually nothing i.e. zero perceptible movement.

A moving iron meter will attract an iron armature irrespective of the direction of the current hence, it will measure AC and usually will measure RMS AC quantities.